# Why wont my component show using async pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular service that has a show and hide method, in those methods a BehaviorSubject.next is called passing either true or false.

```
export class LoaderController {
   isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

   show() {
     this.isLoading.next(true);
   }

   hide() {
     this.isLoading.next(false);
   }
```

}

in a component constructor

```
  export class LoaderComponent {

      isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = this.loader.isLoading;

      constructor(private loader: LoaderController) {}

  }
```

and in the template

```
    <div *ngIf="(isLoading | async)" class="flex flex-center">
      <h3>I show when isLoading is true</h3>
    </div>
```

I have an interceptor that calls the service methods and I have verified with debugging things are being called as expected. Both with breakpoints and `console.log(***)`.

```
    export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
       constructor(public loader: LoaderController) {}
       intercept(
          req: HttpRequest<any>,
          next: HttpHandler
        ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (!req.url.includes('/summary')) {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
         console.warn('LoaderInterceptor');

         this.loader.show();

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
          finalize(() => this.loader.hide())
        );
     }
  }
```

I can't figure out why it's not showing when I call service.show() which sends `true` to the BehaviorSubject.next.  Also if I initialize the behaviorSubject to true, then it shows as expected, but it never stops showing.  The component isn't updating when the show() or hide() is being called. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Could you put a log statement in before the hide as well to see if possibly the show is executing and then the hide immediately after so it looks like the show isn't working?

Comment: Try to change with: *ngIf=(loader.isLoading | async)

Comment: What type of DI is specified for your LoaderController? @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })?

Comment: yes @mrak providedIn: 'root'. I was thinking that maybe the interceptor and the component are using two different instances of the service.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-interceptor-7h5jnm?file=app/http.interceptor.ts